# Event 4771 (Bad Password Logon) Does not show proper client

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller, audit, eventviewer

We are having issues with frequently locked out accounts.

We are having 4771 {Bad Password} events on our main DC.
Issue: Within the event, the client machine is not properly shown. Instead another DC is shown as client host name:
[image]

only in rare occasions the actual client host name is shown. What could be the cause for this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is a logon take place at another Domain Controller, and then subsequently - as with all bad password attempts in Active Directory - the original logon server forwarding the authentication to the DC with the PDC Emulator FSMO role to double-check the password -- to ensure that there wasn't a password change that hadn't been replicated yet, as the PDCe *should* be notified preferentially of any password changes.

The rare occasions when an actual client host name is shown, it is because the PDCe happens to be the original logon server of that request, and does not have to check with any other DC for confirmation.

Comment: I see the same behavior all the time. You just have to ignore the events showing a DC as the source client and focus on the other events as the true source of the bad password.